# Encrypt in java and Decrypt in C# For AES 256 bit

Tags: c#, java, encryption, aes

1.I have java function which encrypt xml file and return encrypted String.

```
/// Java Class 
import java.security.Key;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Crypt {

    public static String key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    public static byte[] key_Array = Base64.decodeBase64(key);

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt)
    {       
        try
        {   
            //Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            //Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            //Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");      

            Key SecretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key_Array, "AES");

            Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");     
            _Cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, SecretKey);       

            return Base64.encodeBase64String(_Cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes()));     
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("[Exception]:"+e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("xml file string ...");

        String EncryptedString = encrypt(sb.toString());        
        System.out.println("[EncryptedString]:"+EncryptedString);
    }
}
```

2.I have c# function which decrypt the message which is encrypted by java function.

```
/// C# Function
private static string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
{
    RijndaelManaged aesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged();            
    aesEncryption.BlockSize = 256;
    //aesEncryption.KeySize = 256;
    //aesEncryption.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    //aesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    string keyStr = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    //string ivStr = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";        

    byte[] keyArr = Convert.FromBase64String(keyStr);
    //byte[] ivArr = Convert.FromBase64String(ivStr);

    aesEncryption.Key = keyArr;
    //aesEncryption.IV = ivArr;

    ICryptoTransform decrypto = aesEncryption.CreateDecryptor();

    byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(encryptedText.ToCharArray(), 0, encryptedText.Length);  
    byte[] decryptedData = decrypto.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length); /// CryptographicException: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.    
    return ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData); 
}
```

Java encrypt function is work well. But the problem is C# function, 
when I decrypt I get below error message

```
CryptographicException: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.
```

I searched solutions by using below ref

1. [AES Encryption in Java and Decryption in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295110/aes-encryption-in-java-and-decryption-in-c-sharp)
2. [C# / Java | AES256 encrypt/decrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584167/c-sharp-java-aes256-encrypt-decrypt)
3. [Encyption/Decryption in C# and Java](http://lamahashim.blogspot.sg/2009/08/encyptiondecryption-in-c-and-java.html)

but I still face the same error.Could anyone give me suggestion please.

### Updated

I Just change my C# crypto function. Below is my change lists

1. Block Size to 128
2. Key Size to 256
3. IV Size to 16
4. Key Size to 32

```
/// Updated decrypt function
private static string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
{
    RijndaelManaged aesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged();            
    aesEncryption.BlockSize = 128;
    aesEncryption.KeySize = 256;

    //aesEncryption.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

    string keyStr = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    string ivStr = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";           

    byte[] ivArr = Convert.FromBase64String(ivStr);
    byte[] IVkey16BytesValue = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(ivArr, IVkey16BytesValue, 16);

    byte[] keyArr = Convert.FromBase64String(keyStr);
    byte[] KeyArr32BytesValue = new byte[32];
    Array.Copy(keyArr, KeyArr32BytesValue, 32);

    aesEncryption.IV = IVkey16BytesValue;
    aesEncryption.Key = KeyArr32BytesValue; 

    ICryptoTransform decrypto = aesEncryption.CreateDecryptor();

    byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(encryptedText.ToCharArray(), 0, encryptedText.Length);
    byte[] decryptedData = decrypto.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length); 
    return ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);
}
```

In this time, no error occur. But I get decrypted message which i cannot read.

```
g:�\0�\td��Y\\符O����\rL��W�wHm�>f�\au����%��0��\ ..........
```

Please let me get your suggestion again.

Comment: I believe the blockSize should be 128 and the keysize be 256.
The keyStr should be 32 characters long and the IVstr should be 16 characters long. This may help as it describes why 128 bits have to be used for block size and what the key sizes can be. http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf

Comment: See if this helps, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5295110/17776

Comment: The default padding mode in C# is PaddingMode.PKCS7. I am not sure it is same in java.I think it is better to specify it in both places

Comment: @deathismyfriend , Please see me updated function again. And I hope that you can give me more suggestion. Thank

Comment: Always a bad thing to use defaults in cryptography. In addition to the other comments I think you should explicitly specify the encoding in the java `String.getBytes()` method. Change `strToEncrypt.getBytes()` to `strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")`

Comment: You have this in the decrypt method. aesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.None;   I believe you need to put that in the encrypt method also.

Comment: Also why not use this method for the key and IV.   
            aes.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyStr);
            aes.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ivStr);

Comment: Have you tried FromBase64String? I'm not so sure you are using "Unicode" (which is the incorrect name for UTF-16LE used in C# if I'm not mistaken)? Could you show us the base 64 string?

Comment: Thank you so much , deathismyfriend, jac, krishnanunni-jeevan, gregs,and owlstead. Because of your help, Now i can solve it.

Comment: Does encrypt algorithm work? Because it always returns null for me? Can you help me?

Comment: Yes, sure it really work, I can help you. if you want more detail about that, then you can send mail to me myatthu1986@gmail.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the blockSize should be 128 and the keysize be 256. The keyStr should be 32 characters long and the IVstr should be 16 characters long. This may help as it describes why 128 bits have to be used for block size and what the key sizes can be. csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf

You have this in the decrypt method.

```
    aesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
```

I believe you need to put that in the encrypt method also.

Also why not use this method for the key and IV.

```
    aes.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyStr); 
    aes.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ivStr);
```

Answer (score 19):

After I got very helpful suggestions from @deathismyfriend and other, I found out what I am missing in my C# Decrypt function.So I change my function as below.

```
/// C# Error Fixed Version - CipherMode.ECB
public static string keyStr = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

private static string Encrypt(string PlainText)
{
    RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
    aes.BlockSize = 128;
    aes.KeySize = 256;

    /// In Java, Same with below code
    /// Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");  // Java Code
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; 

    byte[] keyArr = Convert.FromBase64String(keyStr);
    byte[] KeyArrBytes32Value = new byte[32];
    Array.Copy(keyArr, KeyArrBytes32Value, 32);

    aes.Key = KeyArrBytes32Value;

    ICryptoTransform encrypto = aes.CreateEncryptor();

    byte[] plainTextByte = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PlainText);
    byte[] CipherText = encrypto.TransformFinalBlock(plainTextByte, 0, plainTextByte.Length);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(CipherText);
}

private static string Decrypt(string CipherText)
{  
    RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
    aes.BlockSize = 128;
    aes.KeySize = 256;

    /// In Java, Same with below code
    /// Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");  // Java Code
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

    byte[] keyArr = Convert.FromBase64String(keyStr);
    byte[] KeyArrBytes32Value = new byte[32];
    Array.Copy(keyArr, KeyArrBytes32Value, 32);

    aes.Key = KeyArrBytes32Value;

    ICryptoTransform decrypto = aes.CreateDecryptor();

    byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(CipherText.ToCharArray(), 0, CipherText.Length);
    byte[] decryptedData = decrypto.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
    return ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);
}
```

By using upper c# function , now I can decrypt and read cipher text.
Below is what I found out after I getting error again and again.

```
CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

 Solution:  
_RijndaelManaged.Padding = CipherMode.xxx;    ///should toggle here
_RijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.xxx;   ///should toggle here 


CryptographicException: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid. 
CryptographicException: Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm.

Solution
1. _RijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 128; /// Must be
2. _RijndaelManaged.KeySize = 256; /// Must be
3. _RijndaelManaged.Key = Byte Array Size must be 32 in length ( more detail 32*8 = 256 KeySize )
4. _RijndaelManaged.IV = Byte Array Size must be 16 in length ( more detail 16*8 = 128 BlockSize)
```

But when it come to security reason, I think I should not use ECB mode.
According to

1. [ECB mode is not secure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6671819/900284)
2. [StackOverFlow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669181/why-does-my-aes-encryption-throws-an-invalidkeyexception)

So I Modify it again in Java and C#.

```
// Java code - Cipher mode CBC version.
// CBC version need Initialization vector IV.
// Reference from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669181/why-does-my-aes-encryption-throws-an-invalidkeyexception/6669812#6669812

import java.security.Key;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class CryptoSecurity {

    public static String key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    public static byte[] key_Array = Base64.decodeBase64(key);

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt)
    {       
        try
        {   
            //Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            //Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");        

            // Initialization vector.   
            // It could be any value or generated using a random number generator.
            byte[] iv = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7 };
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

            Key SecretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key_Array, "AES");    
            _Cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, SecretKey, ivspec);       

            return Base64.encodeBase64String(_Cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes()));     
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("[Exception]:"+e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String EncryptedMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            //Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            //Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");            

            // Initialization vector.   
            // It could be any value or generated using a random number generator.
            byte[] iv = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7 };
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

            Key SecretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key_Array, "AES");
            _Cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, SecretKey, ivspec);           

            byte DecodedMessage[] = Base64.decodeBase64(EncryptedMessage);
            return new String(_Cipher.doFinal(DecodedMessage));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("[Exception]:"+e.getMessage());          

        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("xml file string ...");

        String outputOfEncrypt = encrypt(sb.toString());        
        System.out.println("[CryptoSecurity.outputOfEncrypt]:"+outputOfEncrypt);

        String outputOfDecrypt = decrypt(outputOfEncrypt);        
        //String outputOfDecrypt = decrypt(sb.toString());        
        System.out.println("[CryptoSecurity.outputOfDecrypt]:"+outputOfDecrypt);
    }

}
```

In C#, I modify it like below.

```
// C# Code, CipherMode.CBC
// CBC version need Initialization vector IV.

public static string keyStr = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
private static string Encrypt(string PlainText)
{
    RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
    aes.BlockSize = 128;
    aes.KeySize = 256;

    // It is equal in java 
    /// Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");    
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;  
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; 

    byte[] keyArr = Convert.FromBase64String(keyStr);
    byte[] KeyArrBytes32Value = new byte[32];
    Array.Copy(keyArr, KeyArrBytes32Value, 32);

    // Initialization vector.   
    // It could be any value or generated using a random number generator.
    byte[] ivArr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7 };
    byte[] IVBytes16Value = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(ivArr, IVBytes16Value, 16);

    aes.Key = KeyArrBytes32Value;
    aes.IV = IVBytes16Value;

    ICryptoTransform encrypto = aes.CreateEncryptor();

    byte[] plainTextByte = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PlainText);
    byte[] CipherText = encrypto.TransformFinalBlock(plainTextByte, 0, plainTextByte.Length);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(CipherText);

}

private static string Decrypt(string CipherText)
{
    RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
    aes.BlockSize = 128;
    aes.KeySize = 256;

    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    byte[] keyArr = Convert.FromBase64String(keyStr);
    byte[] KeyArrBytes32Value = new byte[32];
    Array.Copy(keyArr, KeyArrBytes32Value, 32);

    // Initialization vector.   
    // It could be any value or generated using a random number generator.
    byte[] ivArr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7 };            
    byte[] IVBytes16Value = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(ivArr, IVBytes16Value, 16);

    aes.Key = KeyArrBytes32Value;
    aes.IV = IVBytes16Value;

    ICryptoTransform decrypto = aes.CreateDecryptor();

    byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(CipherText.ToCharArray(), 0, CipherText.Length);
    byte[] decryptedData = decrypto.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
    return ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);
}
```

Now it all work.

For more detail about AES, [click this link](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf) which I was given by @deathismyfriend. 

It is also very useful.

Comment: glad to help if i helped solve it can u mark my answer as solved. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for clicking the answer button on my answer lol.

Comment: I sent you an invite. I probably won't use that site often tho.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I have the same situation - encryption with java, decryption with C#.  I could not get your code working as is however.  I'm using an older version of the JVM though (1.5).  You never mentioned what version you are using.  And also what version of [org.apache.commons.codec].  I did finally get it working though, thanks to your post.

Comment: I get an error "Key length not 128/192/256 bits." when using the java on android and C# code on the server side. any ideas?

Comment: Also, the size of the key used has to be no more than 16 characters (as per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907530/java-security-invalidkeyexception-illegal-key-size-or-default-parameters-in-and )

Answer (score 2):

On one of my recent projects I was tasked with building up a url with an encrypted portion to pass to another website.  They ran java on their server, whereas we developed in c#.

*I know this isn't an exact match to what you were tasked to create, but hopefully this can help out others that are trying to find answers :)*

I received the following from their developers to build our encryption off from

[image]

To accomplish this in c# I did the following:

```
    public String Encrypt(String plainText, String key)
    {
        var plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(plainBytes, GetRijndaelManaged(key)));
    }

    private RijndaelManaged GetRijndaelManaged(String secretKey)
    {
        var keyBytes = new byte[16];
        var secretKeyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey);
        Array.Copy(secretKeyBytes, keyBytes, Math.Min(keyBytes.Length, secretKeyBytes.Length));
        return new RijndaelManaged
        {
            Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            KeySize = 128,
            BlockSize = 128,
            Key = keyBytes,
            IV = keyBytes

        };
    }

    private byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainBytes, RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged)
    {
        return rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor()
            .TransformFinalBlock(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with this algorithm (in Java only) and I did a litle changes.

[Diff Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKbpj.png)

```
// Java code - Cipher mode CBC version.
// CBC version need Initialization vector IV.
// Reference from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669181/why-does-my-aes-encryption-throws-an-invalidkeyexception/6669812#6669812
public static String key = "FFClY170hLrhsDnKUEhJ4FhVOnrpNNFFClY170hLrhsDnKUE";
public static byte[] key_Array = Base64.decodeBase64(key);

public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt) {
    try {
        //Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        //Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");

        // Initialization vector.   
        // It could be any value or generated using a random number generator.
        byte[] iv = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7};
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        key_Array = Arrays.copyOf(key_Array, 32);

        Key SecretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key_Array, "AES");
        _Cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, SecretKey, ivspec);

        return Base64.encodeBase64String(_Cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("[Exception]:" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String EncryptedMessage) {
    try {
        //Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        //Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");

        // Initialization vector.   
        // It could be any value or generated using a random number generator.
        byte[] iv = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7};
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        key_Array = Arrays.copyOf(key_Array, 32);

        Key SecretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key_Array, "AES");
        _Cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, SecretKey, ivspec);

        byte DecodedMessage[] = Base64.decodeBase64(EncryptedMessage);
        return new String(_Cipher.doFinal(DecodedMessage));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("[Exception]:" + e.getMessage());

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain your solution a bit?

Answer (score 0):

public static void setSecretkeys(string keyvalue)
{        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(keyvalue);
keyvalue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

```
    byte[] result;
    SHA256 shaM = new SHA256Managed();
    result = shaM.ComputeHash(bytes);

    Array.Copy(result, keybytes, 16);
   
   
    //Console.WriteLine("This is the encryption key    " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(keybytes));
}

public string Decryptxx(string text, string keyValue)
{
    setSecretkeys(keyValue);
    byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
    RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
    byte[] key = keybytes;
    aes.KeySize = 128;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    using (ICryptoTransform decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor(key, null))
    {
        byte[] dest = decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);
        decrypt.Dispose();
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dest);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).