# Encryption in C# and Decryption in Android(java)

Tags: java, c#, android, encryption

i am trying to encrypt some data in c# using this code

```
 public static string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "abc123";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }
```

i want to decrypt the encrypted string in Android programming with the same key used in c#., tried searching but not found any solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698272/encrypt-in-java-and-decrypt-in-c-sharp-for-aes-256-bit

Comment: Don't use Unicode encoding, use UTF8 instead.

Comment: According to comments in the code Java/Android PBEKeySpec implements Rfc2898/PKCS#5.

Comment: There are some things wrong with this code. Why don't you just use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor)? It's more secure and has implementations for multiple languages.

Comment: this code works fine in c#,,, i need its implementation in java,,